# how to go to back to a scene in corona sdk after moving to the next scene?

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

i need some help,
im making an app in corona sdk which contains 4 scenes, main, list, tab1, tab2, the main scene takes you to the list scene by a button and the List takes you to tab1 and tab1 takes you to tab2, what im trying to do is make tab2 go back to the scene List by pressing a button, and when i press on the button nothing happens!!

```
local button1 = widget.newButton

    {

    left= 250,
    top= 650,
    defaultFile = "red1.png",
    label = "select chapter",
    font = "Arial",
     fontSize = 34,
    onEvent = handleButtonEvent,
    onPress = function() storyboard.gotoScene( "list" ); end,
    selected = true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using a function to handle the event of the botton with "onEvent = handleButtonEvent"

You should instead use that function to do the transition:

```
-- Function to handle the press of the button
local function handleButtonEvent(event)
    if ( "ended" == event.phase) then
        storyboard.gotoScene("list")
    end
end
```

and

```
-- Creation of the button
local button1 = widget.newButton
{
    -- All your variables here
    onEvent = handleButtonEvent,    
}
```

and you might even be looking for something like this; this function will instead take the user back to the previous scene.

```
-- Function to handle the press of the button
local function handleButtonEvent(event)
    if ( "ended" == event.phase) then
        storyboard.gotoScene(storyboard.getPrevious())
    end
end
```

Comment: thank you, i did that, but its like it goes to the scene list but without changing the contents in tab2! i see tab2, i don't know whats wrong!

Comment: What "contents" in tab2 do you expect to get changed when going to the list scene?

Comment: tab2 shows the score, i want when pressing on the button to go back to the list scene where you can start over!

Comment: Sounds like you haven't correctly created the scenes. I suggest you follow this tutorial: http://www.develephant.net/a-simple-storyboard-framework-for-corona-sdk-part-1/ as it will take you through Corona's storyboard!

Comment: thank you very much, it worked by adding storyboard.removeAll() haha!

Comment: did the answer work out for you Hesa? Any further issues? Else remember to accept the answer so that other users can easily find the solution :)